# How to vertically stack bootstrap elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, heading

I've got a header, paragraph and image, and I want them aligned with the header above the paragraph, and the image to the right. When I run it I get the 3 elements in a horizontal row

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="col-xs-3 paddingtop">Joselin</h1>
        <p class="col-xs-3 bio">
            Growing up in the Caribbean, as a young girl Joselin worked as a
            coffee bean picker, giving her a profound insight into using only
            the freshest, and highest quality coffee beans.
        </p>
        <img class="col-xs-6 meetus" src="meetus.jpeg">      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The title says you want to vertically stack; then you say you want the img to the right; if you run the snippet, they stacked. Which is it?

Comment: I want to vertically stack the h1 over the p with the image to the right, its for a biography. It does not stack vertically on my site. http://stupefied-leavitt-948d09.bitballoon.com/meettheteam.html. If you go to the meet the team page you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `h1` should be above the `p` and the `img`, the best thing would be to put it in its own row: `<div class="row">`. Then put the `p` and the `img` in a row right under that.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1 class="paddingtop">Joselin</h1>
            <p class="bio">
                Growing up in the Caribbean, as a young girl Joselin worked as a
                coffee bean picker, giving her a profound insight into using only
                the freshest, and highest quality coffee beans.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img class="col-xs-6 meetus" src="meetus.jpeg">      
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can then play around with the column sizes (`class="col-xs-3").

Comment: Sorry I meant I need the h1 above the p, but the image to be to the right of both elements. Thank you.

Comment: Updated. You can adjust the image-padding. Also work on explaining your requirements clearly.